# Time limit exceeded error. what does it mean?

Tags: c, time, limit, exceed

I want to write a C program that prints the maximum of 10 integer numbers. but i get this error. what is the problem?(error is: time limit exceeded)

```
int main()

{
    int arr[9];
    int i;
    int max=-1;

    for(i=0;i<=10;i++) {
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);

        if(arr[i]>arr[i+1]){
            arr[i]=max; 
        }  
    }
    printf("%d",max);
 }
```

program works like that,thank u for help

```
int main()

{
    int arr[9];
    int i;


       int max=-1;



    for(i=0;i<=9;i++) {

        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);

        if(arr[i]>max) {

            max=arr[i]; }  }

            printf("%d",max);

    }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Time limit exceeded error

Comment: You are reading **11** integers, hence your program never finishes, as it is getting passed only 10 integers.

Comment: How are you running this program? Are you running it in an online IDE, for example?

Comment: This sounds like something being done by the environment you're using to run your code.

Comment: @GregHewgill I believe he's trying one of those programming challenges websites.

Comment: If you want to have 10 numbers, why are you declaring an array that can only hold 9 of them? And then reading 11 of them?

Comment: @user3086167 When you receive an error you should provide the complete error message with your question.

Comment: I don't even get the logic, how can you be comparing `arr[i]` to a number you haven't read in yet?

Comment: i am running this script over an online ide.  i have arranged the numbers of array and for loop. not getting that error anymore but program gives false results

Comment: Ben u are right.  i changed the part of the code as u say. and it works it should be : if(arr[i]>max) and this part for(i=0;i<=10;i++)  should be like that for(i=0;i<=9;i++)

Comment: make the change in your post and not as a comment

Comment: I'm still wondering why there is an array in this *at all*. You need *two* numbers (three if you include the loop counter): the one you just read, and the max so far. if the former is greater than the latter, gratz, you have a new max so assign it and move to the next iteration. There is nothing in your description whatsoever to indicate an array is warranted.

Comment: i know u can also solve this prob without arrays but i just wanted to use array. thats all lol. and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

you are indexing two past the end of the array. you need to make the for condition this:

```
for(i=0;i<9;i++)
```

Comment: if he wants to find the max he's got more problems

Comment: yep. no bounds checking. didnt even see that

Comment: if(arr[i]>arr[i+1])  that part should be like that:  if(arr[i]>max)  and this part for(i=0;i<=10;i++) should be like that for(i=0;i<=9;i++)